# Getting child from GestureOverlayView in Android

Tags: android, view, android-layout

I am trying to get TextView as a child element from GestureOverlayView.

here is my view xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/gestureOverlayView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="1" android:layout_width="260dp" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:baselineAligned="false" android:layout_weight="0.32">
                <CheckBox android:id="@+id/sListCheckbox"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.32"></CheckBox>
                <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/sListText" android:layout_width="212dp" android:ems="15" android:layout_gravity="center" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.32"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView android:paddingRight="0dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_weight="0.32" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/searchbutton"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And i am trying to reach TextView like this but i am getting nullPointerException on childText

```
adapterLine.gestureOverlayView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

 if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {

    RelativeLayout llt = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
    TextView childText = (TextView) llt.getChildAt(4);
```

Comment: At what line is the program crashing? Can you post the exception/error log? My guess is that you are not getting the correct parent view. Please post the code where you 
get v.

Comment: childText returning null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by using this

```
RelativeLayout  llt = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
GestureOverlayView gow = (GestureOverlayView) llt.getChildAt(0);
LinearLayout ll1 = (LinearLayout) gow.getChildAt(0);
LinearLayout ll2 = (LinearLayout) ll1.getChildAt(0);
TextView childText = (TextView) ll2.getChildAt(1);
```

i cannot use

```
TextView childText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sListText);
```

this because i am getting v view from my motion event listener on my list view and i do not know exactly which textview is returning.

Comment: Does the gestureOverlayview ontouchevent working for you? I am not able to get it work

Answer (score 1):

You are calling RelativeLayout llt = (RelativeLayout)v.getParent(); --> your variable says llt for LinearLayout, 
but you are getting a RelativeLayout? Try this:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
TextView childText = (TextView)ll.getChildAt(1); // it may be 2 depending on if the root is 0 or not, cant remember
```

Actually why not just do this:

```
TextView childText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sListText);
```

?